# requestChannel.Request hangs

Tags: c#, wcf, channel

I have a c# application that reads a database table and sends messages based on that table. It loops until everything that must be send is send.

My application logs show this:

```
2019-06-13 10:39:39,164 DEBUG GeoBagService.BerichtenSchrijver - Send message met ID :510
2019-06-13 10:39:41,196 INFO GeoBagService.BerichtenSchrijver - Message send :510
2019-06-13 10:39:41,237 DEBUG GeoBagService.BerichtenSchrijver - Send message met ID :502
2019-06-13 10:39:41,610 INFO GeoBagService.BerichtenSchrijver - Message send :502
2019-06-13 10:39:41,652 DEBUG GeoBagService.BerichtenSchrijver - Send message met ID :508
2019-06-13 10:40:41,907 ERROR GeoBagService.BerichtenSchrijver - Error sending message :508
System.Exception: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding.
```

This means that two messages have been send and that the third message times out.

Google searches point to problems with the receiving end. For example that it might still be busy processing the previous request. I'm reasonably certain this is not the case here. But first let me show you the code that is being used to send the message.

```
private bool VerzendBericht(XmlReader xmlReader)
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();
            string action = Utils.UrlCombine(StUFBG.ns.BG, xmlReader.LocalName);

            bool retval = false;
            int bufSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;

            MessageVersion messageVersion;

            messageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11; 

            IRequestChannel requestChannel = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(Settings.Properties.EndpointBag);
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(uri);

            try
            {
                CustomBinding customBinding = new CustomBinding();
                customBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                customBinding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                customBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                customBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

                customBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement() { MessageVersion = messageVersion });

                HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement;
                httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement(); 
                httpTransportBindingElement.TransferMode = TransferMode. Streamed;
                httpTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = bufSize;
                httpTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = bufSize;
                httpTransportBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = bufSize;

                customBinding.Elements.Add(httpTransportBindingElement); 

                using (ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(customBinding, address))
                {
                    requestChannel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();  
                    requestChannel.Open();

                    Message request = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, action, xmlReader);
                    Message reply = requestChannel.Request(request);   // <--- This is where it hangs
                    retval = VerwerkReply(reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
                    reply.Close();

                    requestChannel.Close();
                }

                if (requestChannel is IClientChannel icnl)
                    icnl.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ExceptionName == null || !ExceptionName.Equals(ex.GetType().Name))
                {
                    ExceptionName = ex.GetType().Name;
                    Foutmelding = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            return retval;
        }
```

When sending messages in a loop the process hangs after a number of messages on the line:

```
 Message reply = requestChannel.Request(request);   // <--- This is where it hangs
```

Wireshark output shows that the first two message have been posted but there's no post for the third message. How can that be?

```
82  09:48:11,488763 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 66   29511 → 3080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
83  09:48:11,507026 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 54   29511 → 3080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=084   09:48:11,507375 10.191.1.111
84  09:48:11,507375 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 350  29511 → 3080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=296 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]   
85  09:48:11,527506 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 3755 29511 → 3080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=297 Ack=26 Win=65536 Len=3701 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
86  09:48:11,527646 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    HTTP/XML 59 POST /GeoBagService/OntvangAsynchroon HTTP/1.1 
87  09:48:11,597215 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 54   29511 → 3080 [ACK] Seq=4003 Ack=907 Win=64768 Len=0
110 09:48:16,342428 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 66   29512 → 3080 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
111 09:48:16,360324 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 54   29512 → 3080 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=0
112 09:48:16,360532 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 326  29512 → 3080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65536 Len=272 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
113 09:48:16,386961 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 7447 29512 → 3080 [PSH, ACK] Seq=273 Ack=26 Win=65536 Len=7393 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
114 09:48:16,387013 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    HTTP/XML 59 POST /GeoBagService/OntvangAsynchroon HTTP/1.1 
115 09:48:16,447775 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 66   [TCP Dup ACK 113#1] 29512 → 3080 [ACK] Seq=7671 Ack=26 Win=65536 Len=0 SLE=899 SRE=904
116 09:48:16,447805 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 54   29512 → 3080 [ACK] Seq=7671 Ack=904 Win=64768 Len=0
381 09:49:20,528584 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 54   29511 → 3080 [RST, ACK] Seq=4003 Ack=907 Win=0 Len=0
382 09:49:20,528675 10.191.1.111 172.20.7.39    TCP 54   29512 → 3080 [RST, ACK] Seq=7671 Ack=904 Win=0 Len=0
```

It seems that no traffic gets through after the first two messages.

Other things I've tried:
In debug mode I halted the sending process just before it creates a channel. This gave me time to restart receiving process to make sure it isn't busy. 
I've increased timeout values to 10 min.

This did not help much as it seems that nothing is being send in the first place.

WCF tracing on the receiving end confirms that noting is being received after the first two message.

Perhaps the sending code leaves much to be desired. I'm very new to this.

Comment: Can you check if  calling `icnl.Dispose();` after `icnl.Close();` resolves your issue somewhat? Also check if putting a higher vaue here helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.maxservicepoints?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks, no luck unfortunately. A colleague gave me some more tips on closing and disposing channels and channelfactories.. Things do point to problems in that area.